# Convert integer to a char buffer for serial communication...?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, int

I have a structure as follows

```
struct msg {  
uint16_t data1;
int data2;
}
```

I am sending it through the serial port after converting the structure data into a string (char buffer).

I am actually using **memcpy** to copy the contents into the buffer (using PRAGMA for struct packing)

The problem what I face is the **puts** function of my board, will stop once it encounters a NULL character (ie if 1 bye is 0, as ASCII equivalent o decimal 0 is NULL)

if data2 = 12 then the memory after memcpy will be 00 00 00 0C (HEX). One puts sees the first 00 it stops and returns.

I cannot change my serial port setting or the puts function. 
**What is best method to convert int into  4 byte's in char buffer without any  byte being 0**

Comment: You have three choices. The first is to stop sending binary data and send an ASCII formatted number instead. The second is to use a function that's designed for binary data, something other than `puts`. The third is to encode the entire string using something like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: You should search for "serialization" or "marshalling". In any way, you should not just send a binary image of the `struct`.

Comment: _"What is best method to convert int into 4 byte's in char buffer without any byte being 0"_ Well use a conversion to a character string.

Comment: Are you sure the only way to access the serial port is via `stdout`?

Comment: Why can't you use something other than `puts`? That makes no sense. Use `fwrite` which is designed to send binary information. There is no answer to your actual question so you are going to have to compromise somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending data from microcontroller to the computer using tiva series c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029503/sending-data-from-microcontroller-to-the-computer-using-tiva-series-c)

Comment: The sending part is an already existing framework..I can not change that....Only way is to format the integer in a way that it does not contain NULL character (decimal 0)

Comment: Pidgeonhole principle says you lose.

Comment: @MarkRansom How to send a  ASCII formatted number, in 4 bytes of char array..?

Comment: @JoseJohnThottungal You should add some information about the actual communication protocol. You either need to send the data in binary format (probably using network byte ordering), then you use a `write()` function. Or you need to send text encoded data, well but you're right, that can't be managed within 4 bytes. Anyway there are also formats (like used in DVB standards partially) that want to see [decimal binary encoded numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Comment: @JoseJohnThottungal Fact is, you can't represent a binary encoded integer without containing `0` bytes.

Comment: @JoseJohnThottungal you can't, converting to ASCII might produce 11 digits (10 if unsigned). Is there some reason you need to keep it to 4 bytes? Are your values limited, or can they be any 32-bit value?

Comment: When sending multi-byte values, like integers, outside of your computer (including files), keep in mind the difference between **Big Endian** versus **Little Endian** order.  Which does your receiver want?

Answer (score 2):

[`puts()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) is designed for sending null terminated strings.  It's not the right function to use for sending binary data:

- binary data is not guaranteed to be null terminated, causing `puts()` to send more data than needed.
- binary data might embed '\0' chars which would end prematurely the output
- binary data might embed other special chars that may cause harm, if your standard output is open in text mode, depending on your system/environment.

The right solution depends on the environment/compiler/library you are using for your microcontroler. There are often some special functions for serial I/O (via UART/USART).  But if you are allowed to use `puts()`, you could certainly use [`putchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) to output byte by byte.

```
 msg m;  
 int sz = sizeof(m); 
 for (char*p=reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m); sz--; p++) 
     putchar(*p);
```

If you're obliged to use `puts()` at all cost, one way could be to [convert the buffer in printable hex digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25327667/3723423) and send this string. The hex ditigts will require twice the size of your message (+1 null terminator).

Comment: Or you simply use one of `std::ostream` `write()` variants.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes of course : that would be much more efficient !  But I've understood that he OP was somehow limited in his choice of functions.

Comment: Your idea about the hex digit representation is pretty slick. Anyway OP should clarify about their actual communication protocol.